# The Community user is stuck at 1 reputation in a team

Tags: support, stack-overflow-for-teams, community-user

When a Team is created, there are some questions asked by a Community.

Here’s the weird part: *no matter how much I upvote Community, their reputation is stuck at 1.*

Why?

Comment: the system should remove all upvotes automatically, when you exceed 2 votes

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because Community is a robot, not a person. It cannot gain reputation, neither on the main site nor on a Team. Its reputation is always fixed at 1. This is by design.

Its moderator-like privileges are granted by the diamond, not by virtue of it having reputation and earning privileges. Unlike a "normal" user, Community always keeps its privileges, even with a reputation of only 1.

As an aside: perhaps you're just doing it for testing purposes, but I would be remiss not to mention that the primary purpose of votes should be to indicate the usefulness of a *specific post*, not to bestow reputation upon its author. You shouldn't be upvoting posts by a user just to grant that user some reputation.

Comment: "*Reputation is a rough measurement of how much the community trusts you;*" [source](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) Therefore, Community doesn't trust itself. Which is sad when you think about it.

Comment: @VLAZ Community should *not* be trusted! It's gotten into delete wars with moderators, approved spam edits, serially upvoted users, and engaged in all sorts of other bad behavior.

Comment: Ban the community! Wait...

Comment: I feel like that was tried at least once already, actually...

Comment: @CodyGray: Hold my beer….

Comment: @CodyGray: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lDOB0.jpg Perfectly possible. It won’t stop them from doing All The Things, but we can suspend Community! And apparently, no one tried before, at least not _here_ on SO: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXWmR.jpg

Comment: "It cannot gain reputation, neither on the main site nor on a Team. Its reputation is always fixed at 1." - something tells me that if you post about that on Twitter, people will start to want to cancel you for not giving the robot the same possibilities as a human being.

Comment: @Gimby Community is [not a robot](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/6381/not-a-robot?userid=-1) according to Stack Exchange. So, the network is fairly limiting the opportunities of non-robotic beings - not based on the robotic status.

Comment: Am I the only one now waiting for a reply from Community or even a question along the lines of "Why was I suspended for doing my job?" :P

Comment: @Gimby Good thing I'm not on Twitter, I guess.

Comment: @VLAZ If you look, you'll note that the only requirement for that badge is that someone on staff has met the user. I think we've all met Community!

Comment: The canonical is *[Who is the Community user?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19738)* (part of the FAQ). *"It seems to edit posts sometimes. ... And why has it downvoted over 1800 times?"*